Powershell will not retrigger PowerShell Script after Enabling and Running Task Schedular
Trying to set up task schedule to run my powershell script every 5 minutes.
I have validated secpol, permissions (including run as batch functions as expected), all file and folders are permissioned accordingly
I even logged onto ISE as the service account and it ran fine. Moreover, after configuring it in Task Scheduler I forced a run, and it worked as expected.
Now that I have it scheduled it just sits there .. mocking me. Maybe another set of eyes can see where I went wrong.
Settings:

General
- Account: my-svc-account
- Run whether user is logged on or not
- Run with highest privileges
- Windows Server 2019

Trigger
- Begin the task: On a Schedule
- Daily
- Recur every: 1 days
- Repeat task every: 5 minute
- for a duration of: Indefinitely
- Stop task if it runs longer than: 30 minutes
- Enabled

Actions
- Start a Program
- Program/script: powershell.exe
- Arguments: -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -file D:\myscripts\totalizer9000.ps1
- Start In: D:\myscripts

Conditions

- Power: Start the task if the computer is on AC
- Power: Stop if the computer switches to battery

Settings

- Allow task to be run on demand
- Run task as soon as possible after a sched..
- Stop the task if it runs longer than
- If the running task does not end...
- Do not start a new instance


Deferred to system adminstrators to fix issue with LOCAL SYSTEM not being able to execute powershell
